# HTML5, JQuery - Capture an Image from a mobile device AND save it?

Tags: jquery, html, mobile, capture

```
<input id="image_box" type="file" accept="image/*" capture>
```

Given the above code, I can successfully "capture" an image taken by any mobile device, which is great!

However, I would like to ALSO save this image to the mobile device's default image folder as well.  (Just like it normally does when you take a picture.)

Is this possible to do?  (E.g. Capture the image from the form input, and also save it to the device.)

Much thanks!

Edit: I just verified that the approach I was using (E.g. Adding a "download" attribute to an anchor tag, will and does work for downloading images to PC & Android devices!  But, the same approach does not work for IOS.  So this question is changed to, "Is it possible to save to an IOS device's default photo folder?"

Thanks again!